# python polars - cancelling part of query plan

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

Is there a way to cancel part of query plan added to the polars lazyframe?

e.g. my current process seems like this (*note: my actual query plan is more complex than this*)

**1. Concat all the data**

```
week_data = pl.scan_parquet(one_week_data[0])

for day in one_week_data[1:]:
    temp = pl.scan_parquet(day)

    week_data = pl.concat([week_data, temp])
```

**2. Then rearrange the columns position and choose only some of the columns**

```
week_data = week_data.select([
    'OID_',
    'Hashed_Device_ID',
    'Lat_of_Observation_Point',
    'Lon_of_Observation_Point',
    'Polygon_ID',
    'Unix_Timestamp_of_Observation_Point',
    'Local_Timezone_of_Observation_Point'
])
```

Let's say that I want to cancel the select without having to start over from the concat part, **is there a way I can do that?**

Answer (score 0):

Polars is designed to be a lazy framework, which means that operations are not executed immediately but added to a query plan that will be executed once it's necessary. In the current implementation of Polars, there isn't a direct way to cancel or remove an operation that has been added to the query plan. However, you can work around this limitation by saving intermediate steps into separate variables.

For example, in your case, you can save the week_data variable after the concatenation step and before the select operation:

```
#Concat all the data
week_data = pl.scan_parquet(one_week_data[0])

for day in one_week_data[1:]:
    temp = pl.scan_parquet(day)
    week_data = pl.concat([week_data, temp])

# Save intermediate result
concatenated_data = week_data

# Rearrange the columns position and choose only some of the columns
selected_data = week_data.select([
    'OID_',
    'Hashed_Device_ID',
    'Lat_of_Observation_Point',
    'Lon_of_Observation_Point',
    'Polygon_ID',
    'Unix_Timestamp_of_Observation_Point',
    'Local_Timezone_of_Observation_Point'
])
```

Now, if you want to 'cancel' the select operation, you can simply use the concatenated_data variable instead of selected_data. This way, you do not have to start over from the concatenation step.

Comment: I can see this as a work around. But there will be many variables as the query get more complex.